# I cannot find the problem in this code for cropping the face in the bounding box and then saving it

Tags: android, flutter, dart, face-detection, google-mlkit

I have the code for an app that detects faces from the live camera feed and it works perfectly fine. I want to implement a method that crops the face when it is detected and save it on my pc. I have written the code but I cannot seem to find the problem. For testing, if it saves it I have a print line. When I start the app for debugging, that message which is supposed to show in the terminal, is not shown. I do not know where the problem is, when cropping or when saving. This being my first app, I have little knowledge when it comes to this.

```
**THIS IS MY FACE DETECTION**
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_face_detection/google_mlkit_face_detection.dart';
import 'detector_view.dart';
import 'painters/face_detector_painter.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;



class FaceDetectorView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FaceDetectorView> createState() => _FaceDetectorViewState();
}

class _FaceDetectorViewState extends State<FaceDetectorView> {
  final FaceDetector _faceDetector = FaceDetector(
    options: FaceDetectorOptions(
      enableContours: true,
      enableLandmarks: true,
    ),
  );
  bool _canProcess = true;
  bool _isBusy = false;
  CustomPaint? _customPaint;
  String? _text;
  var _cameraLensDirection = CameraLensDirection.front;
  late final FaceDetectorPainter _painter;

   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _painter = FaceDetectorPainter(
      [],
      Size.zero,
      InputImageRotation.rotation0deg,
      CameraLensDirection.front,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _canProcess = false;
    _faceDetector.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DetectorView(
      title: 'Face Detector',
      customPaint: _customPaint,
      text: _text,
      onImage: _processImage,
      initialCameraLensDirection: _cameraLensDirection,
      onCameraLensDirectionChanged: (value) => _cameraLensDirection = value,
    );
  }

  // Method to crop the detected face
  Future<Uint8List?> cropFaceImage(Face face, ui.Image originalImage) async {
    final left = face.boundingBox.left.toInt();
    final top = face.boundingBox.top.toInt();
    final width = face.boundingBox.width.toInt();
    final height = face.boundingBox.height.toInt();

    final outputWidth = 200; // Adjust as needed
    final outputHeight = 200; // Adjust as needed

    final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final canvas = Canvas(recorder);

    final src = Rect.fromLTWH(left.toDouble(), top.toDouble(), width.toDouble(), height.toDouble());
    final dst = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, outputWidth.toDouble(), outputHeight.toDouble());

    canvas.drawImageRect(originalImage, src, dst, Paint());

    final picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final img = await picture.toImage(outputWidth, outputHeight);
    final byteData = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

    return byteData?.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  Future<void> _processImage(InputImage inputImage) async {
    if (!_canProcess) return;
    if (_isBusy) return;
    _isBusy = true;
    setState(() {
      _text = '';
    });
    final faces = await _faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);
    if (inputImage.metadata?.size != null &&
        inputImage.metadata?.rotation != null) {
      final painter = FaceDetectorPainter(
        faces,
        inputImage.metadata!.size,
        inputImage.metadata!.rotation,
        _cameraLensDirection,
      );
      _customPaint = CustomPaint(painter: painter);
    } else {
      String text = 'Faces found: ${faces.length}\n\n';
      for (final face in faces) {
        text += 'face: ${face.boundingBox}\n\n';
        final croppedFace = await _painter.cropFaceImage(face, inputImage);
        _saveImageLocally(croppedFace);
      }
      _text = text;
      // TODO: set _customPaint to draw boundingRect on top of image
      _customPaint = null;
    }
    _isBusy = false;
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

Future<void> _saveImageLocally(Uint8List? imageBytes) async {
  if (imageBytes == null) {
    print('Image bytes are null. Cannot save.');
    return;
  }

  try {
    // Get the user's home directory
    final String homeDir = path.join(Directory.systemTemp.path, 'CroppedImages');
    final Directory userDirectory = Directory(homeDir);

    // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!await userDirectory.exists()) {
      await userDirectory.create(recursive: true);
    }

    // Generate a unique file name
    final String fileName = '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png';

    // Write the image bytes to a file
    final File file = File(path.join(userDirectory.path, fileName));
    await file.writeAsBytes(imageBytes);

    print('Image saved successfully: ${file.path}');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error saving image: $e');
  }
}
}

**THIS IS MY FACE PAINTER**
// import 'dart:math';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_face_detection/google_mlkit_face_detection.dart';

import 'coordinates_translator.dart';

import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class FaceDetectorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  FaceDetectorPainter(
    this.faces,
    this.imageSize,
    this.rotation,
    this.cameraLensDirection,
  );

  final List<Face> faces;
  final Size imageSize;
  final InputImageRotation rotation;
  final CameraLensDirection cameraLensDirection;

  Future<Uint8List?> cropFaceImage(Face face, InputImage inputImage) async {
    // Get the image byte data
    final Uint8List? bytes = inputImage.bytes;
    if (bytes == null) return null;

    // Construct a Codec from the byte data
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);

    // Get the next frame from the Codec
    final ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();

    // Get the image from the frame
    final ui.Image image = frameInfo.image;

    // Calculate stride
    final int stride = image.width;

    // Convert face bounding box to integers
    final int x = face.boundingBox.left.toInt();
    final int y = face.boundingBox.top.toInt();
    final int width = face.boundingBox.width.toInt();
    final int height = face.boundingBox.height.toInt();

    // Calculate cropped image width and height
    final int croppedImageWidth = width ~/ 2;
    final int croppedImageHeight = height ~/ 2;

    // Create a Uint8List to hold the cropped image data
    final Uint8List croppedImageData =
        Uint8List(croppedImageWidth * croppedImageHeight * 4);

    // Extract pixel data from the image and copy it to the cropped image data
    final ByteData? byteData =
        await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);
    final Uint8List? imageBytes = byteData?.buffer.asUint8List();

    if (imageBytes != null) {
      for (int j = 0; j < croppedImageHeight; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < croppedImageWidth; i++) {
          final int srcOffset = ((y + j) * stride + x + i) * 4;
          final int destOffset = (j * croppedImageWidth + i) * 4;

          // Copy pixel data
          croppedImageData[destOffset + 0] = imageBytes[srcOffset + 0]; // Red
          croppedImageData[destOffset + 1] = imageBytes[srcOffset + 1]; // Green
          croppedImageData[destOffset + 2] = imageBytes[srcOffset + 2]; // Blue
          croppedImageData[destOffset + 3] = imageBytes[srcOffset + 3]; // Alpha
        }
      }
    }

    return croppedImageData;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint1 = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..color = Colors.black;

    for (final Face face in faces) {
      final left = translateX(
        face.boundingBox.left,
        size,
        imageSize,
        rotation,
        cameraLensDirection,
      );
      final top = translateY(
        face.boundingBox.top,
        size,
        imageSize,
        rotation,
        cameraLensDirection,
      );
      final right = translateX(
        face.boundingBox.right,
        size,
        imageSize,
        rotation,
        cameraLensDirection,
      );
      final bottom = translateY(
        face.boundingBox.bottom,
        size,
        imageSize,
        rotation,
        cameraLensDirection,
      );

      canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom),
        paint1,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FaceDetectorPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.imageSize != imageSize || oldDelegate.faces != faces;
  }
}
```